# Correct img path, but I get question mark php

Tags: php, html, css

I want to show an IMG in my Images folder,
I have the correct path, but I get a question when I show the image.

Code:

```
$filename = 'Images/img1.png';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo '<img src="' . $filename . '"/>';
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

[image: structure]

Comment: In your 'Image' folder or 'Images' folder ? ;)

Comment: Can you show your folder structure? Also, how is your webpage hosted?

Comment: It's local, I've added a image of my folder structure

Comment: can you try to `var_dump(file_exists($filename))` before the `if statement`? and show the result?

Comment: result: bool(true) The file Images/img1.png exists

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to check file permissions? This is the most recent problem, when you see that the file exists but it cannot be displayed because of permissions.

If you are using IIS try to assign read permissions for **IIS_IUSRS** on the file or images folder.

If you are using Linux, just change file permissions for the file (*chmod* command). As a starting point try to assign **777** permissions to the file just to check if it changed something.

Comment: I've changed the file/folder permissions, but that doesn't solve it

Comment: Are you able to display the image entering its path directly in browser?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same code you have give above and its working perfect. So, try after giving permission to your images folder.
And, you can also check the exact issue by executing the image path url prefixed with your local directory path in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path...

```
$filename = '/absolute/path/to/your/folder/www/Images/img1.png';
/*
* OR better...
* $filename = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."Images".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR."img1.png";
* dirname(__FILE__) is the directory of your current script... If you have level before use:
* dirname(dirname(__FILE__))
*/

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo '<img src="' . $filename . '"/>';
    echo "The file $filename exists";
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
```